# Make pytest output like googletest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, googletest

I'm using PyTest for python code testing. Since I use googletest for my C++ code testing, I like the output format of googletest.

I'm wondering, is it possible to make pytest output like googletest? The pytest output line is too long, while googletest is short:

// pytest example:

```
(base) zz@home% pytest test_rle_v2.py
================================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.1, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
hypothesis profile 'default' -> database=DirectoryBasedExampleDatabase('/home/zz/work/test/learn-hp/.hypothesis/examples')
rootdir: /home/zz/work/test/learn-hp
plugins: env-0.6.2, hypothesis-4.38.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                         

test_rle_v2.py .                                                                                                                                                                   [100%]

=================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.46s ====================================================================================
```

// googletest example

```
(base) zz@home% ./test_version 
[==========] Running 5 tests from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 5 tests from VERSION
[ RUN      ] VERSION.str
[       OK ] VERSION.str (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] VERSION.parts
[       OK ] VERSION.parts (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] VERSION.metadata
[       OK ] VERSION.metadata (1 ms)
[ RUN      ] VERSION.atLeast
[       OK ] VERSION.atLeast (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] VERSION.hasFeature
[       OK ] VERSION.hasFeature (0 ms)
[----------] 5 tests from VERSION (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 5 tests from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 5 tests.
```

Comment: You can, but it is no one-liner and nothing that can fit in an answer. You need to write a plugin that replaces `pytest`'s default `TerminalReporter` with your custom version. If you need an example, `pytest-sugar` does that IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

After several hours searching and trying, I found a `conftest.py` file required for my purpose. In conftest.py, people can override default pytest function, i.e. by providing hooks.

The following is an WIP example:

```py
# conftest.py

import os
import random

def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    item.add_report_section("call", "custom", " [ Run      ]  " + str(item))

def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    #print(">>> outcome:", report.outcome)

    if report.when == 'call':
        # line = f' [ Run      ]  {report.nodeid}'
        # report.sections.append(('ChrisZZ', line))
        if (report.outcome == 'failed'):
            line = f' [   FAILED ]  {report.nodeid}'
            report.sections.append(('failed due to', line))

    if report.when == 'teardown':
        if (report.outcome == 'passed'):
            line = f' [       OK ]  {report.nodeid}'
            report.sections.append(('ChrisZZ', line))

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    reports = terminalreporter.getreports('')
    content = os.linesep.join(text for report in reports for secname, text in report.sections)
    if content:
        terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
        #terminalreporter.section('', sep=' ', green=True, bold=True)
        #terminalreporter.section('My custom section2', sep='------]', green=True, bold=True, fullwidth=None)
        terminalreporter.line(content)
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder if they enable that kind of maleability and scenario in current versions